# Issues with combining meshes

Tags: mesh, armature, sculpting

So I have been joining meshes and for some reason when I join a mesh and a hand mesh. The hand mesh gets all messes up as you can see in the second picture. But when I combined other meshes together in the same project it worked just fine even with armature but not with the hand mesh I made for some reason...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To join meshes ideally they should have the same scale (set to 1:1:1 with Ctrl+A -> Apply Scale) and there should be no modifiers active (under the Wrench symbol on the right). Maybe one of these is causing issues?

Comment: Your a life savor. Thanks man:) My other account was shut down because the q wasnt good enough but Im glad you could help me:)